# Solr qf field ordering impact on search

Tags: solr, lucene

**My issue:** 
When doing search, 'content' is getting higher priority over my other fields.

**Solr search request handler:**

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
      <str name="q.op">AND</str>
      <str name="qf">title^15.0 description^9.0 categoryNames^3.0 authorName^1.0 content^1.0</str>
      <str name="boost">scoreA</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="appends">
      <str name="fq">private:false</str>
      <str name="fq">deleted:false</str>
      <str name="fq">draft:false</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Here's the scoring from my Solr response:

```
100% 0.003303376 ((content:world | title:world^15.0 | categoryNames:world^3.0 | description:world^9.0 | authorName:world) (content:war | title:war^15.0 | categoryNames:war^3.0 | description:war^9.0 | authorName:war))~2,FileFloatSource(field=scoreA,keyField=id,defVal=0.0,dataDir=/opt/solr/current/data/resource/)
0.95% 0.005617031 sum of the following:
0.27% 0.0016038928 (MATCH) max of:
0.27% 0.0016038928 content:world
0.68% 0.004013138 (MATCH) max of:
0.68% 0.004013138 content:war
99.05% 0.5881     float(scoreA{type=ext_resource_float,properties=indexed,stored,omitTermFreqAndPositions})=0.5881
```

**Breakdown of scoring: http://explain.solr.pl/explains/73itib4r**

From what I can see, 'content' is getting top priority. Not sure why this would be as I have this last in my Solr qf field.

I need 'content' to be the lowest impactor and title the highest.

Answer (score 1):

The order in your parsedQuery `(content:world | title:world^15.0 | categoryNames:world^3.0 | description:world^9.0 | authorName:world) (content:war | title:war^15.0 | categoryNames:war^3.0 | description:war^9.0 | authorName:war))` doesn't mean that the first field is a prior field. The only thing which is important is the weight to each field.

To prove it, you can see that your content field only represent 0.27% of your total score which is the behaviour that you want :

`0.27% 0.0016038928 (MATCH) max of:
 0.27% 0.0016038928 content:world`